# MimeMailMessage problems to send email

Tags: html, vb.net, email

I am making a program to send a mail in vbnet. I'm making a table in HTML and adding some color to some cells, but when I send the email the receiver doesn't see the colors. Why?

Comment: Can you please post some example code ([Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) or a [Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/))?  Include what you've already tried and where exactly you're stuck. See more info at [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) Thanks!

Comment: Dim i As Integer
            html.AppendLine("<table cellspacing=10><tr>")
            For Each col As System.Data.DataColumn In dt.Columns
                html.AppendLine("<th>" & col.Caption & "</th>")
            Next
            html.AppendLine("</tr>")
            For Each dr As System.Data.DataRow In dt.Rows
                html.AppendLine("<tr>")

Comment: For i = 0 To dr.ItemArray.Length - 1
                    html.AppendLine("<td align=center style= background-color=#95FF95 >" & dr.ItemArray(i).ToString & "</td>")
                Next
                html.AppendLine("</tr>")
            Next
            html.AppendLine("</table>")

Comment: html is a system.text.stringbuilder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are missing the quotes

Also in your background style you use EQUAL when you should use COLON

```
Dim i As Integer 
'
'Table
html.AppendLine("<table cellspacing='10'>") 

'Header Row
html.AppendLine("<tr>")
'Header Cells
For Each col As System.Data.DataColumn In dt.Columns 
  html.AppendLine("<th>" & col.Caption & "</th>") 
Next 
'End of Header Row
html.AppendLine("</tr>") 

'Data Rows
For Each dr As System.Data.DataRow In dt.Rows 
  html.AppendLine("<tr>")
  'Data Cells
  For i = 0 To dr.ItemArray.Length - 1 
    html.AppendLine("<td align='center' style='background-color: #95FF95;'>" & dr.ItemArray(i).ToString & "</td>") 
  Next 
  'End of Data Row
  html.AppendLine("</tr>") 
Next 
html.AppendLine("</table>")
```

Don't forget to use quotes too!

Comment: Hi, sorry, yeah i found out later, but yes, thant is the answer!| Thanks Zeddy!